# dockerfile for running meteor app - using node:7.5.0-alpine

Tags: meteor, docker

I am trying to run a meteor app on docker.

here is my Dockerfile:

```
From node:7.5.0-alpine
RUN meteor npm install --a
CMD ["meteor"]
```

running:

```
➜ docker build . -t myapp
Sending build context to Docker daemon 21.91 MB
Step 1 : FROM node:7.5.0-alpine
 ---> 0895ecd79009
Step 2 : RUN meteor npm install --a
 ---> Running in 1de3ba593bb1
/bin/sh: meteor: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c meteor npm install --a' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

this is the error received:

**/bin/sh: meteor: not found**

**The command '/bin/sh -c meteor npm install --a' returned a non-zero**

what did I do wrong?

basically  I'm trying to create my image using a light weight meteor Base Image (`node:7.5.0-alpine`)

what should be fixed in my dockerfile?

Comment: `node:7.5.0-alpine` is not a Meteor base image - you have to install Meteor first

Comment: @chazsolo what Meteor image do you recommend? Id rather use a light weight image

Comment: You could try [ulexus/meteor](https://hub.docker.com/r/ulexus/meteor/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended using [martinezko/alpine-meteor](https://hub.docker.com/r/martinezko/alpine-meteor/) image

Dockerfile

```
FROM martinezko/alpine-meteor
ENV NODE_ENV=production
```

running `docker-build.sh` to build it:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

# get the image tag
echo -n "Enter release tag [e.g. 1.0.7] "
read TAG
echo "You release has an amazing tag: $TAG"

REGISTRY=us.gcr.io
CONTAINER=my-com/my-app
BUILD_DIR=`pwd`/.build                      # <-- This is where meteor build your files.
                                            #     Folder will be created and after build will be deleted


echo "Start building container ${CONTAINER} ..."

# clean old build if exist
rm   -rf $BUILD_DIR
mkdir -p $BUILD_DIR

# install node packages
meteor npm install --a &&

# build meteor app
meteor build --directory $BUILD_DIR --architecture=os.linux.x86_64 --server-only &&

# pull fresh base image:
docker pull martinezko/alpine-meteor:latest &&

# build container
docker build --rm -t ${REGISTRY}/${CONTAINER}:${TAG} . &&


echo "${REGISTRY}/${CONTAINER}:${TAG}"
# push to our registry
echo "we are now pushing your amazing relese to google container engine registry $REGISTRY/$CONTAINER:$TAG"
docker push ${REGISTRY}/${CONTAINER}:${TAG}


# clean images if needed
# docker rmi -f ${CONTAINER}:${TAG} ${REGISTRY}/${CONTAINER}:${TAG} martinezko/alpine-meteor:latest

# to run your container
# docker run -d ${REGISTRY}/${CONTAINER}:${TAG}
# OR use docker-compose.yaml file
# docker-compose up -d

# clean build folder
rm -rf .build

echo "End build of container ${CONTAINER} ..."
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to install meteor first, node is not enough.
try adding something like:
`RUN curl "https://install.meteor.com/" | /bin/sh`
at the 2nd line.
[This is an example for a dockerfile for mongo based on a node image.](https://hub.docker.com/r/anh4n/meteor/~/dockerfile/)

Comment: why not use:
`FROM ulexus/meteor` in the  dockerfile?
isnt this better?

Comment: if that image is good for you, than why not use it...anyhow, you must have meteor on your image to run meteor on it :)